# Apollo federation - error field is marked as @external but is not used by a @requires, @key, or @provides directive

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a schema which extends type `School` which is configured in another schema.
In my `gql` file I have configured my schema and this is how the `School` type is configured:

```
  type School @extends @key(fields: "id") {
    id: String @external
  }
```

The `School` type also has another property `name`, but when I add it I get an error:

```
type School @extends @key(fields: "id name") {
   id: String @external
   name: String @external
}
```

`is marked as @external but is not used by a @requires, @key, or @provides directive.`

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Nor a big expert, but found the same error and solve it by tagging the field with @provides like:

```
type School @extends @key(fields: "id name") {
    id: String @external
    name: String @external
}

extend type Query {
    """
    Note the @provides
    """
    school: School @provides(fields: "name")
}
```

This should work if your intention is that the current subgraph resolves the name field instead of the graph that owes School type.
You can find more info at [federation provides](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federation-spec/#provides)